# How to release a Image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to release pictures until they'll be loaded again.
I load them with this code:

```
_backgroundImage1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld.jpg", random() % 5]];
```

This is how I change the alpha

```
if (backCount == 100) {
        if (currentBack ==YES) {

        _backgroundImage1.alpha = _backgroundImage1.alpha - 0.01;
        _backgroundImage2.alpha = _backgroundImage2.alpha + 0.01;

        if (_backgroundImage2.alpha >= 1) {
            backCount = 0;
            currentBack = NO;
            NSString*path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", arc4random() % 4] ofType:@"jpg"];
            UIImage *Image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
            _backgroundImage1.image = Image;

            //_backgroundImage1.image = nil;
            //_backgroundImage1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld.jpg", random() % 5]];

        }
    } else {
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: You dont have memory ownership of the image so you shouldn't release it?

Comment: The picture is only used every minute maybe every 30 seconds this depends on random but I don't want that the app uses 50MB of Ram for only showing 4 pictures!

Comment: Yes I know that already but I haven't changed it yet because I first wanted to use not as much memory for that. I look for an animation that fades over from one random picture to an other random picture

Comment: If you want to fade between images, then just do `transitionWithView` with an `options` value of `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve`. No timer every 0.05 seconds needed. No manual adjustments of `alpha` needed. And the fade animation is likely to be even smoother than your 0.05 second timer. All you need to do is trigger when you want to start the next transition to the next image (which you could use a timer for, or just initiate it from the completion block of the previous transition). See my expanded answer.

Comment: thanks I'll try that tomorrow here is now 1 am I can't concentrate anymore  thanks for your help :) I'll write tomorrow again. I now do it with `[UIImageView commitAnimations]` where I set alpha to zero and one. For your method below I still need a timer so I think the result is the same?

Comment: Personally, if you wanted to immediately transition to the next image as soon as the previous animation finished, I'd initiate the next image change in the completion block. But transitionWithView should be smoother than a timer every 0.05 seconds. And if you want to change image every, say, two seconds, you could have timer call this transitionWithView once every 2 seconds. It just depends upon what you're going for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `imageNamed` caches images. If you don't want it to be cached, use `imageWithContentsOfFile`.

As the `imageNamed` documentation warns us:

> If you have an image file that will only be displayed once and wish to ensure that it does not get added to the system’s cache, you should instead create your image using `imageWithContentsOfFile:`. This will keep your single-use image out of the system image cache, potentially improving the memory use characteristics of your app.

Thus, you would:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", random() % 5] ofType:@"jpg"]; 

_backgroundImage1.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

---

You've subsequently said that you're looking for "an animation that fades over from one random picture to an other". In that case, every time you change the image, you might just want to do:

```
// fade from current image to new image

[UIView transitionWithView:imageView duration:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", random() % 5] ofType:@"jpg"];
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    // do whatever you want at the end
}];
```

Comment: Do you think it's better to cache the pictures I use them approximately every 30 seconds? Or load them again ? Because from memory consumption it's nearly the same

Comment: @user3642382 No, memory consumption will not be the same. Using `imageNamed` will keep them _all_ in memory at the same time, whereas `imageWithContentsOfFile` will only have the current one in memory at any given time. The cached `imageNamed` will be faster, but takes a lot more memory. If the images are tiny and not too numerous, then caching them is fine. But if they're sizable or manifold or no longer needed when you go somewhere else in the app, then the `imageNamed` cache is not prudent.

Comment: The Images are the backgrounds and they are only a few hundred kilobytes but in iPhones Memory in Simulators memory it takes MBs because it caches every pixel with 4 bytes ? For me it means to save 15MB of ram but it has always to read the picture from flash ?

Comment: @user3642382 Yes, when you load a JPG or PNG (which are both generally compressed), when iOS uses the image, it will generally take up four bytes per pixel uncompressed (one byte for red, green, blue, and alpha). And if those are full screen bitmaps (esp retina quality), that will add up quickly. But yes, if you don't cache, it will have to re-retrieve the images from persistent storage every time. It's the traditional tradeoff. Frankly, you should look at your animation and see if it can be rendered programmatically rather than by swapping images, which is horribly inefficient.

Comment: Yes I even asked how to animate a fade in fade out. But everyone said that that is the easiest way to realize that

Comment: @user3642382 Yikes, definitely not. Do you want me to show you how to fade in and fade out, removing the image view when you're done?

Comment: yes the code is in the question now :) There is a timer that calls the method every 0.05s and after the else it's the same code only the ImageViews are changed

Answer (score 0):

With ARC:

```
_backgroundImage1=nil;
```

assuming that -backgroundImage1 is the only (strong) reference that is kept to the image.

Without ARC

```
[_backgroundImage1.image release];
```

Well, the this could be dangerous assuming that _backgroundImage1 is an instance of UIImageView or whatever that still wants to access its property image. So

```
_backgroundImage1=nil;
```

would be a good idea here too.

Comment: Be patient. Do you ARC?

Comment: It does. But similar to other programming environments with automatic reference couting and garbage collectors and all the works, nullifiying all references does not release the objects immediately. Be patient and allow the framework to do its work. If you perfer to be in control of the memory management then just don't ARC.

Comment: @HermannKlecker While I understand your intent here, your ARC suggestion will not release memory (because you're `nil`ing your pointer to a `UIImageView` that is still presumably a subview somewhere and this will do nothing to release the underlying `UIImage`, but merely just losing your ability to reference that `UIImageView` anymore). Your second, non-ARC suggestion, is even worse, because when you eventually do set `_backgroundImage1.image` to `nil`, you will end up over-released the object and likely crash. He should simply `_backgroundImage1.image = nil;` (in both ARC and non-ARC).

Comment: The issue is the cache, not a failure to release the `UIImage` properly.

Comment: but I want to set imageview to nil too but my code doesn't allow that really otherwise dimming alpha won't work anymore

Comment: @user3642382 If you want to `nil` the `_backgroundImage1` for other reasons, then, fine, do that (though that's meaningless unless you also `removeFromSuperview`, and setting it to `nil` is redundant if `_backgroundImage1` is a `weak` pointer). But that's to solve a very different problem (i.e. that you no longer need the image view), and that's very different from your original question (i.e. you don't want to hold on to the memory associated with image as you jump from one to the next).

Answer (score 0):

imageNamed: caches images locally. From the docs:

> This method looks in the system caches for an image object with the specified name and returns that object if it exists. If a matching image object is not already in the cache, this method loads the image data from the specified file, caches it, and then returns the resulting object.

If you want it to load the image from disk each time, use imageWithContentsOfFile:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourImageName" ofType:@"yourImageFileType"];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

Comment: Thanks that works :) I think with this hardware I don't need to release the pictures really but I don't want that the app already uses 50MB for showing 4 pictures every minute